# How long can I leave a freshly baked cheesecake out before it goes in the refrigerator?

Tags: baking, food-safety, cheesecake

We just baked a cheesecake and are heading over to family's house for the rest of the evening. Is it ok to leave the cheesecake out for 6 hours or so before being refrigerated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referring to the quotes from the below links;

> • “Baked cheesecake should be refrigerated as soon as it is cool or it
>   may develop harmful bacteria from heat resistant spores.”
>   http://www.canfightbac.org/cpcfse/en/cookwell/ask/dairy/#2085
>
> • “Foods made with eggs and milk such as pumpkin pie, custard pie and
>   cheesecake, must first be safely baked to a safe minimum internal
>   temperature of 160 °F. Then, they must be refrigerated after baking.
>   Eggs and milk have high protein and moisture content and when these
>   baked products are left at room temperature, conditions are ripe for
>   bacteria to multiply. It's not necessary to refrigerate most other
>   cakes, cookies or breads unless they have a perishable filling or
>   frosting.” 
>   http://www.fsis.usda.gov/factsheets/Hotline_Answers_Panic_Button_Questions/index.asp

**When to throw it out;** a quote from the link below;

> “Refrigerator Foods    When to Save and When to Throw It Out
>   FOOD.....................   **Held above 40 °F for over 2 hours**
>   Cheesecake............    **Discard**
>   http://www.fsis.usda.gov/factsheets/keeping_food_safe_during_an_emergency/index.asp